# Thinkpad L412 Fan not working and some fn keys as well

Tags: laptop, bios, fan, thinkpad

I have a problem with my laptop which is following :

- The cooling system had completely stopped working
- Some hot keys doesn't respond anymore (brightness, sound)

First of all, I was thinking about an OS problem (i'm running debian), so I try Windows & Ubuntu, still the same problem.

Afterwards, I thought about a BIOS problem, so I decide to upgrade this one, by using the BIOS utility whatever boot CD and it solved the problem.

But now one week after I had solved it, the problem is back and because I'm on the last bios firmware I can't upgrade anymore. So I don't know what I can do.

Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness:

I had the exact same problem with my L412. To my surprise, the working solution is **to unplug the power cable, remove the battery and then press and hold the power button for a couple of seconds**. Wait about a minute to insert the battery again and power up your thinkpad.

After this procedure, your fan and keys are working fine again. Though I don't really get the cause of this phenomenon...

Comment: This worked for my L412 as well. Looked for hours for any help with bios updates, fan controls. Can't believe this was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it's a driver issue on both machines, do you have thinkpad-acpi in Linux and are you using the Lenovo drivers in Windows?

Regarding the BIOS have you tried resetting it, "load factory defaults" or the like?

If you leave the machine in BIOS does the fan come on then?